# How to find out what time and date an iBook was finished?

Tags: mac, ipad, books, ibook

I finished reading an iBook last night on the Mac (or possibly could have used the iPad too), and marked it "Finished" when I flipped the book beyond the last page of the book and tapped Finished.

So this morning, I wanted to check: when did I read the book until... was it 9pm or was it 11pm?

Also, I hope to perhaps in the future, find out, in year 2022, which books did I finish. (so it'd be nice if it can show the books finished sorted by date).

Is it possible to show the finish date and time of an iBook, and be able to see the list sorted by date and time?